# SVN - best strategy to synchronize a branch

Tags: svn, merge, synchronization, branch

Imagine I have a feature branch. For any reason, I need to update it with the latest developments from the trunk (which include more developments than my branch).

Which strategy would you apply ?
1/ merge into my branch the developements from the trunk
2/ create a new branch from latest trunk and apply the developments done in my branch.

With solution 1, can it cause problems when I reintegrate the branch into the trunk ?. If I resolve a conflict during the first merge (trunk->branch), will I have to solve it again during the second merge (branch->trunk) ?

Which solution do you suggest ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: If this is going to be a messy merge, then I would totally recommend strategy 2 -- create a new branch from trunk and merge your changes into it.  That way if something goes wrong you have not polluted your original branch. OR, just TAG your current branch before you merge and you can easily revert back to the TAG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to create a new branch from the latest trunk and merge your feature branch into this new branch. This way, when you merge your feature branch into this replica of trunk, you're merging code that you did yourself: something you know well. If there are any conflicts with this, you are in a good position to resolve them.

Later, you can merge this new branch back to trunk. Again, you will be merging changes you are familiar with.

This is a pretty simple merge strategy, since all the merges go in one direction:

- feature1 -> feature2
- feature2 -> trunk (reintegrate)

Answer (score 0):

You can start with synchronizing with the trunk since this is the normal way to do so, and see what appen. In case you see there is too much difficulties solving synchronization conflicts, you can revert to your clean branch and try solution 2.

Solution 2 may only be prefered if you are really ready to reintegrate, otherwise you will have extra work to synchronize. Or then your development branch will change from branch 1 to branch 2 where you merged, and next time you will create a branch 3 and so on ...

Concerning resolution of conflict you can always adopt the safe strategy or "their changes" or "their full". Remind that in your workdir you can mess up things and revert.
You can eventually accept all 'their conflicts' and replay your changes explicitely, which will have same effects of solution 2 without having to create temporary branch.

Also a huge portion of changes on trunk may not be related with your development, and if you have few changes, it does not matter how much other changes there is on trunk, you will not have more conflicting code than the amount of code you wrote.

Concerning your second question: if it can cause problem when you reintegrate, no it shouldn't provided you use the --reintegrate option.
Anyway even if it will, you shouldn't worry because result of 'merge' or of 'merge --reintegrate' only applies in your workdir. So that you can test-and-fix or revert.

```
cd workdir
svn merge ^/trunk

#resolve conflicts
svn ci
svn update

svn status -q
# to ensure there is no pending changes

svn switch ^/trunk
svn merge --reintegrate ^/branches/your_branch
# resolve conflicts and test or revert

# and only if you are satisfied:
svn ci
svn up

# if your not satisfied:
svn revert
svn merge --reintegrate ^/branches/your_branch
# try resolve conflict in an another way ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

I was asking because there is one drawback with solution 2. The development of the feature is split into many branches, in case I have to synchronize several times. The history of the modifications is a bit more complicated.

I prefer solution 2 in fact.